# Does ShowComposeNewEmailAsync have a maximum Body length?

Tags: uwp

I'm using Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync in a UWP application to send an email message. The argument is an EmailMessage, for which I have provided a recipient, a subject, and a body.

This works fine until the length of the body exceeds around 1200 characters. At that point, the body gets cut off when the email program loads. The problem is the same across several different email clients, so it appears to be a limitation of the API rather than the email client.

I've checked the documentation for both ShowComposeNewEmailAsync and EmailMessage, but neither of them mentions any size limitation (or for that matter, much of anything else).

Does anyone know if this is in fact a limitation? If so, is there a way around it? My messages are not huge, but some of them need to be longer than 1200 characters.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

`EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync` actually invokes the mail application through the `mailto:` protocol.

Therefore, this character limit should be the maximum url length limit that the corresponding mail application or service. Such as [Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/208427/maximum-url-length-is-2-083-characters-in-internet-explorer).

As an alternative, you can convert to an attachment for sending when judging that the current character exceeds 1200.

```cs
public async Task SendMailAsync(string receiver,string subject,string msg)
{
    EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage();
    emailMessage.To.Add(new EmailRecipient(receiver));
    emailMessage.Subject = subject;
    int length = msg.Length;
    if (length > 1200)
    {
        string messageBody = "Please check the attachment";
        emailMessage.Body = messageBody;
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile attachmentFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("TempMail.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(attachmentFile, msg);
        if (attachmentFile != null)
        {
            var stream = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(attachmentFile);
            var attachment = new EmailAttachment(
                     attachmentFile.Name,
                     stream);
            emailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        emailMessage.Body = msg;
    }
    await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
}
```

---

Update

> Attachments that you add to an email by using the EmailAttachment class will appear only in the Mail app. If users have any other mail program configured as their default mail program, the compose window will appear without the attachment. This is a known issue.

Comment: Note that using attachments only works when using the *Windows Mail App*! [see here for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email)

Comment: My customer is using Outlook. I got the above code to work with the Windows Mail app, but it won't work with Outlook. Is there another way to do this that will work?

Comment: Thanks @Leander, This is my negligence, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hi @Flarosa, There is currently no related document about calling Outlook in UWP to send attachments (it is a known issue that attachments cannot be delivered in not `Mail` application). You can remind users to manually start Outlook to send emails when the amount of text is detected to be out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Zhang proposed a good solution to your problem, however this only works when using the windows mail app.
Since you mentioned using Outlook, you may take a look at [MsgKit](https://github.com/Sicos1977/MsgKit).

> As this is another way of sending emails, you may want to look whether this package supports longer messages, otherwise using the attachment workaround may work here.